# Problem reading a GZip csv into python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, gzip

i have the following file that is over 2m rows.

It is a csv but saved as gzip file.

[image]

When i try to read it into pandas though i get the following:
FileNotFoundError: File b'logs.csv' does not exist

I have tried the following different ways for reading it in:

```
df = pd.read_csv('logs.csv', nrows=20)
df = pd.read_csv('logs.csv', compression='gzip',nrows=20)
df = pd.read_csv('logs.csv.gz', compression='gzip',nrows=20)
```

But all return the same file cant be found error

Also, os is saying the file does not exist as well.

```
os.path.exists('logs.csv')
Out[13]: False
```

I have double checked and python is in the correct directory.

Does anyone know what the problem might be and how i can read it in with pandas?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: isn't your filename supposed to be logs.csv.gz ?

Comment: yes thats correct it works now